# Compute a Python program to find how many years the CPI will have at least doubled from its July 2014 level

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The consumer price index (CPI) indicates the average price of a fixed basket of goods and services. It is customarily taken as a measure of inflation and is frequently used to adjust pensions. The CPI was 9.9 in July 1913, was 100 in July 1983, and was 238.25 in July 2014. This means that $9.90 in July 1913 had the same purchasing power as $100.00 in July 1983, and the same purchasing power as $238.25 in July 2014. In 2009, the CPI fell for the first time since 1955. However, for most of the preceding 15 years it had grown at an average rate of 2.5% per year. Assuming that the CPI will rise at 2.5% per year in the future, in how many years will the CPI have at least doubled from its July 2014 level? Note: Each year, the CPI will be 1.025 times the CPI for the previous year. See example of the output below.

**My current Coding:**

```
c = 1
year = 0
inc = 1.025
while (c >= 1):
    c *= (inc ** year) == 238.25 * 2
    year += 1
print(year)
```

I can only get the result of one year from my current coding and I wonder if I set anything wrong in my current code especially for the while loop. My while loop condition may be wrong but I don't know how to fix it right.

**Expected Output of the Program:**
Consumer prices will
double in 29 years.

Comment: Can you explain what you think this line means? `c *= (inc ** year) == 238.25 * 2`

Answer (score 0):

Your target is current * 2, your CPI grows at 2.5% each year. So just keep increasing your CPI until you hit the target.

```
year = 0
inc = 1.025
current = 238.25
target = current * 2
while current <= target:
    current *= inc
    year += 1
print(year)
```

Output:

```
29
```

Comment: Should I use current <= target or current < target inside the while loop in this program?

Comment: <= since the multiplication might yield an exact result

Comment: so both are fine since both <= and < still produce exact result (i.e. 29 years)

Comment: In this example, yes. But might not be for all inputs

Answer (score 0):

A while loop that does this:

```
cpi = 1
i = 0
while cpi < 2:
    i += 1
    cpi = 1.025 ** i

print(i) # 29
```

Or a for loop (that assumes a max 1000 years, just as a placeholder):

```
for i in range(1000):
    if 1.025 ** i > 2:
        print(i)
        break
```

Both print out the correct answer = 29